# NimbusLeaderNotFoundException in Apache Storm

Tags: virtualbox, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to make an Apache Storm Demo example based on here: http://www.allprogrammingtutorials.com/tutorials/setting-up-apache-storm-cluster.php

So far, I have created 2 virtual machines with Oracle VM VirtualBox and uploaded both of them Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Only their IP addresses are different and RAMs are 2GB in both. Otherwise it is like in the example.

In the example, there is this sentence I didn't understand well:

> Updated /etc/hosts file on both the virtual machines with the IP address of other virtual machines. E.g. /etc/hosts on VM1 will need to have IP address of VM2 along with hostname (VM2). In my case, this additional line in VM1 hosts file looks like 192.168.111.132 VM2.

When I ifconfig, I get 2 IPs 192.168.0.74 and 76. However in the /etc/hosts files it is written:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       master-Virtualbox      (slave1-VirtualBox in other)

192.168.0.76    slave1-VirtualBox   (master-VirtualBox and 74 in other)
```

There may be something wrong in here.

Anyway, in both VMs apache storm and zookeeper are uploaded and I start both zookeepers as server (because in the example link, it is like that). Then I start nimbus in VM1 and supervisor in slave1. But in the both UIs I get NimbusLeaderNotFoundException.

Zookeeper confs:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/home/master/Downloads/zookeeper-3.4.8/data   (slave1 instead of master in the other)
dataLogDir=/home/.../zookeeper-3.4.8/logs
clientPort=2181
server.1=192.168.0.74:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.0.76:2888:3888
```

Storm.yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "192.168.0.74"
    - "192.168.0.76"
nimbus.host: "192.168.0.74"
storm.local.dir: "/home/.../apache-storm-1.0.1/data"

# only in slave
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
```

What is the problem here and how can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading your post, there are things I would like you to check:

First: make sure you can ping each VM from the other, and if you are using NAT, remember that the VM's can only be seen if they are executing on the same machine.

Second:Wich version of Storm are you using? certain versions conflict if you run zookeeper on the same machine than nimbus or supervisors, try a single zookeeper conf, just in case.

Third: can you post a log from nimbus, zookeeper or UI? The logs can tell us a lot of things.

Tell me if some of these had helped you.